# Consecutively apply a list of filters to a set in Python with a comprehension

Tags: python

I have a list of functions which I want to consecutively apply to a set, so I'm left only with the items of the set that pass all the functions

This is my current implementation:

```
filtered = starting_set
for combinations_filter in self.combination_filters:
    filtered = filter(combinations_filter, filtered)
```

Is there a way of doing this is a single line comprehension?

Comment: How does one "pass" a function? Does that function return True?

Comment: `self.combination_filters` is a list of functions

Comment: what is returned from the functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed. What you need to do is `and` all of your filters together, getting this:

```
combined_filter = lambda x: all(f(x) for f in self.combination filters)
filtered = filter(combined_filter, starting_set)
```

The `all` means the filter returns `True` only if it passes all of the filters.

Comment: And python should be clever enough to return `False` as soon as one of the filters returns `False`, right? So it's not calculating every function for every element?

Comment: Yes. `any` and `all` short-circuit